# Tkinter - Updating text plotting using set_text

Tags: python, tkinter, settext

I have values in a 2D array which I ploy them using the following lines:

```
t1 = [[self.ax.text(i+.2,n-.6-j,myArray[0][j][i])
        for i in range(myArray.shape[2])]
        for j in range(myArray.shape[1])]
```

and I'm trying to update them using this:

```
t1.set_text(myArray[self.ref][0][0])
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'set_text'
```

However, which I try to update one value only, like:

```
    t1 = self.ax.text(10,10, myArray[0][0][0])
```

it works just fine.
My questions is: How can I update the plotting of the values of the whole array at once? And by update I mean removing the previous values and plotting the new once so they don't pile up.

**Addition**

I tried applied the solution mentioned here: 
[How to refresh text in Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223286/how-to-refresh-text-in-matplotlib) 

and extend it to my problem, still didn't work.

Comment: `t1` in python's list, not plot, and it doesn't have `set_text()`. With `t1 = self.ax.text()` you replace list with different object and you can do the same wiithout `t1 =`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t1` is 2D list with many `text` elements and you can do the same with something like

```
t1 = []

for j in range(myArray.shape[1]):
    sublist = []        
    for i in range(myArray.shape[2]):
       txt = self.ax.text(i+.2,n-.6-j,myArray[0][j][i])
       sublist.append(txt)
    t1.append(sublist)
```

So you can do something similar with `set_text()` to change text

```
for j in range(myArray.shape[1]):
    for i in range(myArray.shape[2]):
       t1[i][j].set_text(myArray[0][j][i])
```

or using `enumerate()`

```
for j, row in enumerate(t1):
    for i, cell in enumerate(row):
       cell.set_text(myArray[0][j][i])
```

or using `zip()`

```
for row, arr_row in zi(t1, myArray[0]):
    for cell, arr_cell in zip(row, arr_row):
       cell.set_text(arr_cell)
```

BTW: all examples are not tested so they may need some changes.

---

Using `t1 = self.ax.text(10,10, myArray[0][0][0])` you replaced list with single element so you loose access to all elements.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first solution and it worked well. I have another question I don't know if I shall post in a separate question. I want to remove the added text using a button with one click. I have been trying with something like `t1.remove()`, however it's not working. Could you help me please in this issue as well?

Comment: `t1` is python list, not text on `plot` - and it has method `remove()` which removes item from list (which is only reference to text item on `plot)`, not item from `plot`. To remove text from plot you have to get element from list and use matplotlib method to remove it - `t1[0][0].remove()` . For more elements you have to use `for` loops.